# How to deploy Next.js in Amplify?

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I don't know why this happens.

> 2021-09-18T00:04:20 [INFO]: Beginning deployment for application
> dhq4kye8grbzc, branch:main, buildId 0000000028
>
> 2021-09-18T00:04:20 [INFO]: Cannot find any generated SSR resources to
> deploy. If you intend for your app to be SSR, please check your app
> Service Role permissions. Otherwise, please check out our docs on how
> to setup your app to be detected as SSG
> (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#deploy-nextjs-app
> )
>
> 2021-09-18T00:04:20 [ERROR]: {"code":"7","message":"No
> ssrResources.json file"}

[image]

Comment: Any luck fixing this problem? I am also facing this error

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it by myself I was facing the same issue. The main problem is you are setting Next version: 11 which is not possible. As of today, we can either use 9,10 or the latest. So latest basically means version 11.

The configuration can be updated in Build Setting in your Amplify Console Platform Dashboard.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you actually solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your amplify service role. I found that going into the general setting and attaching a new role with a `AdministratorAccess-Amplify` managed policy fixed the problem when I ran into it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#ssr-IAM-permissions

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to deploy Next.js app in SSG mode while your Amplify application framework is set to SSR. To change it make sure that while you are connecting a new branch, on Frontend environments tab,  `build` command in `package.json` looks like `"next build && next export"`.

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "next build && next export",
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Base on `package.json` Amplify detects framework.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#deploy-nextjs-ap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#deploy-nextjs-app)